# How to make a new object each time I add a new item to a list python

Tags: python, arrays, oop

So I have a problem like this:

```
array_of_things = [[is_shiny=False, is_bumpy=True]
                   [is_shiny=False, is_bumpy=False]
                   [is_shiny=True, is_bumpy=True]]
```

To access an item, I would do this:

```
if array_of_things[1][1] == True: #If the second item in list is bumpy
    print("The second item is bumpy")
```

However, to make my code more clear, I want each item in an array to be accessed like this:

```
if array_of_things[1].is_bumpy == True: #If the second item in the list is bumpy
    print("The second item is bumpy")
```

How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary object instead of a list inside the outer list?

Comment: If ordering matters you can use OrderedDict.  Also take a look at namedtuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is using `dict` but if you want exactly the syntax given in your question [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) can be used:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Thing = namedtuple('Thing', ['is_shiny', 'is_bumpy'])
array_of_things = [Thing(False, True), Thing(False, False), Thing(True, True)]

if array_of_things[1].is_bumpy == True:
    print("The second item is bumpy")
```

`namedtuple` creates a new subclass of `tuple` which has the typename of first parameter. Fields can be accessed either with an index just like with regular `tuple` or with field name that was passed in a second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If those "things" have an important meaning for your program, I'd suggest to define a class, but otherwise, use dicts:

```
array_of_things = [{'is_shiny': False, 'is_bumpy': True},
                   {'is_shiny': False, 'is_bumpy': False},
                   {'is_shiny': True, 'is_bumpy': True}]

if array_of_things[1]['is_bumpy']:  # since it's a boolean, no need for `==`
    print("The second item is bumpy")
```